# load json list and process it

Tags: javascript, html, json

I need a piece of application that

- Loads a list of items (i.e.customer details) from a sample JSON object, display them in a list

[image]

- Clicking on each row/item shows a module/popup with individual details
- POST to edit/delete the entry

I tried to show the data in a div but it's not in a list and besides  that I need to add an onclick for each row that would contain the name of the customer and show additional data in the popup window
Can someone help me with this, please? I am new to programming.

package.json

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "firstName": "Mary",
    "lastName": "Peterson"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "firstName": "George",
    "lastName": "Hansen"
  }
]
```

Code

```
fetch('package.json')
    .then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        appendData(data);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('error: ' + err);
    });

function appendData(data) {
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.innerHTML = data[i].firstName + ' ' + data[i].lastName;
        mainContainer.appendChild(div);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Assuming your FETCH works, please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56591539/edit) then click the `[<>]` snippet editor. Give an example of the data and show what you tried with the linking in a [mcve] What you have now is far too little effort for use to help and the question can ve closed as off topic because it is too broad - you are basically asking us to do your work

Comment: Look into [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to get at the parts you want to grab when posting

Comment: @PrasanthGanesan What do you mean. There is a big fat FETCH at the beginning

Comment: I was talking about the declaration part. But I came to know it is a built in API, so sorry for the mistake

Comment: all I need is adding a popup window for each row that contains a name
how could I do that and how could I send data from the json to be shown in the popup?
https://imgur.com/a/Kf0vqiE

Comment: That construct was a mistake
I'll edit it now sorry

Comment: `div.setAttribute("data-id",data[i].id)` will be a start. Then have an eventListener on the container that responds to a click

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for your help

could I use this for the popup?
but how could I use it for every div?

`document.getElementById('a').onclick = function() {
    //do something
    alert("Click Event Fired !")
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I did as considering the data as in a variable. You can use 
[`$.getJSON()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) to fetch the data from a JSON file.

```js
var packageJson;
$(document).ready(function(){

// JSON File Data
packageJson = [
  {
    "id": "1",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Doe"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "firstName": "Mary",
    "lastName": "Peterson"
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "firstName": "George",
    "lastName": "Hansen"
  }
];

// Insert JSON data to html
$.each(packageJson,function(key,value){
  $('#nameList').append('<li data-id="'+value.id+'">'+value.firstName+' '+value.lastName+ '</li>');
});
});

$(document).on('click','#nameList li',function(){
  $userId = $(this).attr('data-id');
  $user = {};
  
  // loop through the json data and fetch the data to the popup
  $.each(packageJson,function(key,value){
    if(value.id === $userId)
      {
        $('#userId p').html(value.id);
        $('#userFirstName p').html(value.firstName);
        $('#userLastName p').html(value.lastName);
        
        $('#myModal').modal('show'); // Show popup
      }
  });
  

});
```

```css
.mainContent{
margin-left:10px;
padding:10px;
}

#myModal .modal-body p{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class='mainContent'> 
  <h3> User List</h3>
  <ul id="nameList">
  </ul>
</div>


<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">User Details</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="userId">
          <label>User Id : </label>
          <p></p>
        </div>
        <div id="userFirstName">
          <label>First Name : </label>
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="userLastName">
          <label>First Name : </label>
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `div.setAttribute("data-id",data[i].id)`

Then use something like this

```js
const resWin = document.getElementById("resWindow");

mainContainer.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  resWin.classList.toggle("show",0);

  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.tagName.toUpperCase() === "DIV") {
    fetch("/details", {
        method: "POST",
        body: '{ "id": "' + tgt.getAttribute("data-id") + '"}'
      })
      .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        resWin.innerHTML = formatNicely(data);
        resWin.classList.toggle("show",1);
      })
  }
})
```

Comment: where will the resWindow fit into the rest of the code? Thank you again for your help

Comment: Just the div popup you have. I charge 50 EUR/hour for custom coding and you are getting this for free